# Getting " Cannot run program "bash"" while building chef in jenkins

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, jenkins, chef-infra

I have installed chef-plugin in jenkins and did the following configurations:
Run chef client on remote host:

```
enabled: checked
ssh host: "remote host"
ssh login: root
chef_json template: "{
  "run-list" :[
   "recipe[test]"
   ]
}"

color output: checked
```

and got the following error:

```
Started by user swetha sreeramoju
Building in workspace C:\.jenkins\workspace\chef-sample
[2015-05-27 19:06:44 +0530] INFO: [34m[47mrendering ERB template[0m[0m
[2015-05-27 19:06:44 +0530] INFO: [34m[47mparsing JSON string[0m[0m
[2015-05-27 19:06:44 +0530] INFO: [34m[47msaving JSON to file[0m[0m
[2015-05-27 19:06:44 +0530] INFO: [2m[1m[34m[47m[4mchef json url[0m[0m[0m[0m[0m[34m[47m : http://localhost:8080/jenkins//job/chef-sample/ws/chef.json[0m[0m
[2015-05-27 19:06:44 +0530] INFO: [2m[1m[34m[47m[4mhost[0m[0m[0m[0m[0m[34m[47m : 10.0.12.209[0m[0m
$ bash -c "ssh root@10.0.12.209 sudo chef-client -l info -j http://localhost:8080/jenkins//job/chef-sample/ws/chef.json  "
ERROR: Cannot run program "bash": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified (Java::JavaIo::IOException)
java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:816)
hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:382)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440)
org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304)
org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:64)
org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:112)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:126)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:163)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:70)
org.jruby.ast.FCallSpecialArgNode.interpret(FCallSpecialArgNode.java:45)
org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:64)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:112)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:126)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:163)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:70)
org.jruby.ast.CallManyArgsNode.interpret(CallManyArgsNode.java:59)
org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgFixnumNode.interpret(CallOneArgFixnumNode.java:59)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:110)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:268)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:220)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:236)
org.jruby.ast.CallThreeArgNode.interpret(CallThreeArgNode.java:61)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:209)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:160)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yieldSpecific(Interpreted19Block.java:133)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:99)
org.jruby.ast.ZYieldNode.interpret(ZYieldNode.java:25)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:224)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:119)
org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:204)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:196)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:177)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:188)
org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallOneArgBlockNode.java:34)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:112)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:126)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:163)
org.jruby.javasupport.proxy.JavaProxyConstructor$2.invoke(JavaProxyConstructor.java:224)
org.jruby.proxy.hudson.tasks.Builder$Proxy2.perform(Unknown Source)
hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:764)
hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1744)
hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)

Build step 'Run chef client on remote host' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Chef client and server is running in Linux machine, and jenkins is configured in Windows7.

Comment: where is bash in your system?

Comment: The server there is clearly **not** linux. Look at the `Building in workspace` line. That is clearly a Windows path.

Comment: I have putty in my machine.

Answer (score 1):

The problems seems a bit wider as explained here [SSH+slaves+and+Cygwin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+slaves+and+Cygwin):

> This is because Jenkins is trying to call Windows API and execute "/bin/bash" without going through Cygwin path translation. Windows interprets /bin/bash as c:\bin\bash.exe, and unless that path exists, it will fail.

A quick solutions is to pass from a linux node.

Another quick possibility is to make an *on-demand* Jenkins node out of the Chef-client linux machine (a few clicks) and run there the proper shell line (although it's probably more an hack):

```
chef-client -l info -j http://localhost:8080/jenkins//job/chef-sample/ws/chef.json
```

Comment: I have tried running the above command in Putty. But am facing connection error.

Comment: Clearly you have to replace the {localhost} with the real ip or hostname of the machine where Jenkins server is running. Then the Jenkins server need to the visible to the chef client. Anyway, as Sven suggested, having this kind of approach is a bit of a perversion. If you have a fresh setup - and no IT contains - I would move the Jenkins server to a good old linux system.

Comment: I did the same. I have replaced localhost and added the ipaddress of where jenkins is running. getting connection error. Is there any other way so that I can overcome this problem?

Comment: Check from a browser on the machine fi you have the credentials to access to http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/chef-sample/ws/chef.json      In addition there's a second "/" which I would remove if not needed.

Comment: The other issue is that you must enable 8080 out on the W7 firewall.

Comment: I have turned off the W7 firewall and now am getting " INFO: HTTP Request Returned 403 Forbidden:
[2015-06-01T05:10:58-04:00] FATAL: Cannot fetch config 'http://ipaddress:8080/jenkins/job/chef-sample/ws/chef.json': 'Net::HTTPServerException: 403 "Forbidden""

Comment: Do you need to login with any Jenkins credential?

Comment: Can reproduce the problem. It seems indeed there's a problem in the plugin not pointing you to the right filepath. Try contacting the plugin developer.

Answer (score 1):

> Jenkins client and server is running in Linux machine, and jenkins is configured in Windows7.

That makes no sense.

- What's "Jenkins client"? The browser that you used to connect to Jenkins? You can connect through any browser on any OS. It has no affect whatsoever on the execution. The execution happens on master/slave nodes.
- "Jenkins [...] server is running in Linux". OK. But then why does your log say `Building in workspace C:\.jenkins\workspace\chef-sample`. Clearly it is running on Windows node. So either there is a Windows slave node that you are not mentioning, or the Jenkins server is not on Linux but on Windows.
- "Jenkins is configured in Windows7". Well, that just continues to add to the confusion. Is Jenkins server running on Windows or Linux, you just said "Linux" in the previous sentence.

Your issue is that you cannot run `bash` in Jenkins on Windows (and everything points to that being the case here), unless you have a `bash` equivalent (Cygwin) installed on Windows

Comment: Jenkins is running in Windows 7 and Chef client and server are in Linux machine.