# Rundeck [ssh-exec] can't find bash

Tags: java, windows, bash, ssh, rundeck

My organization is using Rundeck to execute simple batch jobs throughout their system. We originally configured it to run on a Linux VM such that it would execute jobs on Linux, Solaris and Windows machines. We did not see any issues.

However, we were recently asked to move Rundeck to a Windows host. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get it to run a simple command on my test node (Solaris). Every time I attempt it, I receive the following error:

```
Failed: IOFailure: [ssh-exec] Cannot run program "/bin/bash": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I think the problem has to do with the fact that there is no `/bin/bash` on the host node (that path doesn't even make sense to Windows). The plugin calls [a bash script](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/blob/48b0c71381225096ac67943c1d81a94dfe3436d1/examples/ssh-script-plugin/ssh-example-1.0-plugin/contents/ssh-exec.sh) on the host attempting to use `/bin/bash`. That is specified [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/blob/48b0c71381225096ac67943c1d81a94dfe3436d1/examples/ssh-script-plugin/ssh-example-1.0-plugin/plugin.yaml).

*For reference, there is a `/bin/bash` on the target node. I think the issue may be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484592/getting-cannot-run-program-bash-while-building-chef-in-jenkins).*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the job definition or your command test to take a look? maybe related with this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rundeck-discuss/Ks7BoJmKt38/4iy0L2pf-gwJ

Comment: @ReinerRDECK Sure thing, here's a [job definition](https://gist.github.com/isermaniac/7b5c367ee8e72c5771243505d186660f). I had the same issue whether it was an adhoc command or a job though. I updated my post to reflect my theory on why the problem is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I could find that doesn't require altering a plugin file is to switch to `jsch-ssh` which just uses Java ssh. That way it doesn't rely on the existence of `/bin/bash`.